# The Opposite of Swagger-Core?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am an experienced technical writer but new to the management of Swagger or OpenAPI.

We currently use Swagger-Core, where all the settings are in @Operation or @Parameter within Java or Python files.

However, I have seen set ups where those configuration statements are in yaml files. The biggest advantage is that the text inside a description tag can get as extensive as needed.

Somehow they are connected to the Java or Python files. The configurations get set in the yaml files and they get applied to the Java methods.

What is that system called? How does that get done?

Comment: I would start by reading some [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started).

Comment: Thanks. I did read that but didn't see that it answered my question. Did it and I just missed it?

Comment: It looks like all you do is include a yaml or json file at an expected location and you're good to go. I don't see any specific name for the system. Search for the line reading "Your Own Configuration" and follow the links there.